# SimpleExoPlayerView player property missing

Tags: xamarin.android, exoplayer

after updating my Xam.Plugins.Android.ExoPlayer package to the 2.11.3 version the Player property of the SimpleExoPlayerView has disappeared and gave me error when i tried to fill it...
so basically it does not exist anymore, then what is the alternative ?
this is a pretty new update so i couldn't find any docs on this topic
the ones that i found were outdated and had most of the classes used in them Deprecated[Obsolete]
`_playerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(Context) { Player = _player };`

Comment: Exoplayer 2.9.0 and up requires Visual Studio 2019 with R8 and D8, According to the d8 and R8, you can refer to this thread:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androids-d8-dexer-and-r8-shrinker/

Comment: i already have those enabled my problem that this property is not available anymore and a lot of the stuff are Deprecated so we need some better docs if available

Comment: Here is a link about ExoPlayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer#documentation , Please see the topic of  `Follow our developer blog to keep up to date with the latest ExoPlayer developments!`